# CSV php, using browser variable saved as number, cron as string

Tags: php, csv, cron

When im saving csv file runing my php script in browser everything is ok and my numbers are numbers, but when im runing same script from cron they are saved as strings.

Opening/creating csv:

```
$fp = fopen(PATH.'NAME.csv', 'w') or die('file open failed');
fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
```

Writing to:

```
fputcsv($fp,array($LP,$date, 
                $magazyn["pz"],
                $sprzedaz["suma"],
```

Closing:

```
fclose($fp);
```

Browser and crontab are runing on apache linux user, server runs on debian 9, and php 7.0.
Variables saved are floats in both cases. Checked this before.

csv outcome from browser:

1,2018-07-02,6359.91,7663.8,.....

csv outcome from cron:

1,2018-07-02,"6359,91","7663,8",.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the numbers are formatted using commas as decimal separators, which necessitates them being quoted in CSV, since commas are otherwise understood as field separators.

The reason why PHP is outputting floats with commas instead of periods is either because your data is formatted as such, or because you have set a locale that defines it that way. E.g.:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.UTF-8');
echo 1.2345;  // 1,2345
```

It's possible that your cron user and web server user have different environmental locale settings.

Comment: This is it, didn't notice that separator is diferent:
float(6359.91) vs float(6359,91)